# Windows 7 Starter Network

Tags: networking, windows-7

In my work place we have a small network with computers running Windows 7 Starter and a computer running Windows 7 Professional.

I know Starter can't create a network (share files and printer), so the network was created with the Windows 7 Professional computer and the others joined afterwards, without problems.

My question is if I remove this Windows 7 Professional computer. Will the Windows 7 Starter only network, still be working and sharing files and printers among them?

My boss wants to get the Windows 7 Professional computer to another place but I cannot test it until its gone the next Monday and if the network fails I need a plan B.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up shares (whether printer, file, etc.) on the Win 7 Pro system, and other systems are connecting those shares, when you remove the Win 7 Pro system, those shares will no longer exist, and other systems can no longer connect to those shares.